# Chartboost on Android close button

Tags: android, mobile, plugins, unity-game-engine, chartboost

Currently working with Unity3D and am integrating the Chartboost plugin to show ads. On Android devices (tested on a samsung tablet and a kindle fire device), the ad shows up, but I can't seem to be able to close it using the X button (close button at the top right). I have followed the steps in the unity integration guide : https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/unity

Does anyone know how to deal with this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer pretty fast.

I had forgotten to add the following line in my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

Actually, I had it, but I had forgotten to set it in the activity that contains the following intent filter :

```
<intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> </intent-filter>
```

Cheers !